# Performance considerations of instantiating DbContext for every request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

My project involves entity framework 6, asp.net mvc 5, owin and ninject.

Owin is used because I use ASP.NET Identity. My dbContext `FhtDbContext` inherits from IdentityDbContext.

Since one DbContext per request is the norm, my current solution is as follows:

In Startup.cs:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(FhtDbContext.Create);
```

Then in ninject configuration:

```
kernel.Bind<FhtDbContext>().ToProvider(new CallbackProvider<FhtDbContext>(ctx =>
{
    return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<FhtDbContext>();
})).InRequestScope();
```

However, in this setup, a `FhtDbContext` is created even if a request doesn't need database read/write at all.

So my question is, how expensive is creating a dbcontext and discard it?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs

Comment: @TryingToImprove Thanks, I feel ashamed for not looking into the code before asking. The constructor didn't do anything complicated so I shouldn't worry too much.

Comment: no - and I think that ninject only will instantiate your class if it is being dependent on, and not for static resources.. So I would not worry..

Comment: I used Owin's `CreatePerOwinContext` to new a DbContext regardless of whether it is needed or not, because ASP.NET Identity needs it.In Ninject, I am only retrieving the DbContext stored in the Owin Context.

Comment: "how expensive is creating a dbcontext". Well, the obvious question is: Did you messure this? You are the only one who can determine 1. what the overhead is in your environment and 2.. whether this overhead is acceptible.